# js apply decorator to function in object

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator

```
function decorator(target, key, descriptor) {
    console.log('decorated')
}

class User() {
    subscriptions: {
        @decorator
        function friends() {
        }
    }
}
```

Is there some way so I can use a decorator on any function (e.g. in a property object of a class like above)?